# Lock down SFTP access on OpenSolaris

Tags: sftp, security, opensolaris

I have an OpenSolaris 2009.06 server and I'd like to enable a user to remotely change files in a specific directory, ideally via SFTP or FTP-via-SSH. This user does not yet have an account on the machine and I'd like to create it so it's as restricted as possible. Is there a canonical way of doing this? I know about OpenSolaris' role-based access control and authorizations model, but I figure it's a lot of work (i.e., a lot I can mess up) to really lock down a full-blown user account (prevent fork bombs, make sure there's really no other file in the file system which can be written to...). Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rssh` is probably what you want.

It's a restricted shell with just enough functionality for file transfers and nothing else.

Comment: You might need to wait for the next OpenSolaris release (2010.xx) or switch to the developement build to get rssh support as it was integrated in build 112 and 2009.06 is build 111b if I recall properly.